# Changing all whitespace to line breaks in javascript

Tags: javascript, text, replace, adobe-illustrator

I was modifying a script for Adobe Illustrator in Javascript, when I stumbled upon a fact, that Illustrator does not think that the second line is a function. I am pretty noob around js.

```
var item =  activeDocument.selection[0];

var linebreak = item.replace(/\s+/g, "%0D%0A");
```

Comment: What do you mean 'illustrator does not think that the second line is a function'? What problem are you having?

Comment: 'Error 24: item.replace is not a function'

Comment: …so `item` is not a string

Comment: item isn't a string. if you try item.innerHTML.replace.....does that work?